# Not able to load the default credentials for the google-cloud-text_to_speech Gem in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, google-text-to-speech, figaro-ruby

In my `Rails 5.1.7` application, I want to use a method within a `rake-task` to turn text into a mp3 audiofile. I'm using the `google-cloud-text_to_speech gem` for doing so. Here's part of my setup:

`/Gemfile`:

```
gem 'google-cloud-text_to_speech'
```

Here is the method in the `task-file` that is being called from within the task:

`/lib/tasks/sync.rake`:

```
require "google/cloud/text_to_speech"

def create_speech(content, id)
  text_to_speech_client = Google::Cloud::TextToSpeech.new
  text = content
  input = { text: text }
  language_code = "nl-NL"
  voice = { language_code: language_code }
  audio_encoding = :MP3
  audio_config = { audio_encoding: audio_encoding }
  response = text_to_speech_client.synthesize_speech(input, voice, audio_config)
  File.write("speach_id_#{id}.mp3", response.audio_content, mode: "wb")
  puts "Created speach_id_#{id}.mp3"
end
```

I authenticated it according to the following instructions:
https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-text_to_speech/latest/file.AUTHENTICATION.html

`/config/application.rb`:

```
config.speech = config_for(:speech)
```

`/config/speech.yml`:

```
google:
  project: ENV=["TEXTTOSPEECH_PROJECT"]
  credentials: ENV=["TEXTTOSPEECH_CREDENTIALS"]
```

I'm using `Figaro` for my environment variables and therefore I have an `application.yml` file.

`/config/application.yml`:

```
development:
  TEXTTOSPEECH_PROJECT: "project-id"
  TEXTTOSPEECH_CREDENTIALS: "/path/to/file.json"
```

And then I run my task:

```
$ bundle exec rake sync:feeds
```

When I run the rake task without the extra method, everything works fine. But when I use the method, I'm getting:

```
"rake aborted!
Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials"
```

I've tried many different ways to offer the credentials, but I'm getting the same error time after time. Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: I would suggest putting your credentials inside your `Rails Credentials` file and then referencing the credentials with something like this `Rails.application.credentials.google[:api_key]`.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, Cannon. Isn’t the credentials file something that we use in Rails 6? For this project I’m still in 5.1.7. And where should I reference it? Do I need to replace api_key with another value?

Comment: If I remember correctly credentials were introduced in Rails 5.2 while Rails secrets weren't fully removed until Rails 6. So, if you're on 5.1 I would suggest using secrets. The functionality is very similar to Rails credentials. This should solve your problem with the file not loading. Here is a link to more information about Rails secrets. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml